# Как уважительно говорить о человеке в 3-ем лице единственного числа?

Tags: грамотная-речь, недопустимая-метка

Как с уважением говорить о человеке в 3-ем лице ед.ч.? 
Пример:

1. "Мария Ивановна сказали, что бумаги они (речь идёт об одном человеке - о Марии Ивановне) отправят завтра. Сегодня их нет."
2. "Мария Ивановна сказала, что бумаги она отправит завтра. Сегодня ее нет."

Это должно быть сказано с уважением, как во 2-ом лице ед.ч. - на "Вы". Так как верно? 
Если есть ссылки на правила или статьи по этому поводу, скиньте мне их, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2):

По первому варианту говорили слуги, лакеи и дворня. Барин, мол, приехали.
Так что решайте сами, как вам говорить *с уважением*.